# Replace pagebreak tag with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, magento, preg-replace

Here's what I am tryin to accomplish. The CMS editor of our Magento webshop, has a button to insert a `<!-- pagebreak -->` tag. I would like to use this, to create a *read more* functionality. I thought I would search/replace for this tag to do this.

I want to search inside `<p>` tags, and I want people to be able to use this tag as often as they want.

Suppose this is my original HTML:

```
<p>This is my example text, but<!-- pagebreak --> this should be readable after 'click more'<!-- pagebreak --> with even more click more possible</p>
```

I would like to convert it to something like this.. I think the first one is the easiest to accomplish, maybe by doing an preg_replace in a while loop? The second one is probably cleaner/better html (less nesting)

```
<p>This is my example text, but <a href="#" onClick='#'>read more</a><div class='hiddenreadmore' id='hiddenreadmore-1'> this should be readable after 'click more'<a href="#" onClick='#'>read more</a><div class='hiddenreadmore' id='hiddenreadmore-2'> with even more click more possible</div></div></p>
```

or

```
<p>This is my example text, but <a href="#" onClick='#'>read more</a><div class='hiddenreadmore' id='hiddenreadmore-1'> this should be readable after 'click more'<a href="#" onClick='#'>read more</a></div><div class='hiddenreadmore' id='hiddenreadmore-2'> with even more click more possible</div></p>
```

So I came up with this, but I think there should be a way to do it with one replace.

```php
$pattern = '#\<p\>(.+?)\<\!-- pagebreak --\>(.+?)\<\/p\>#s';
$count = true;
while ($count) {
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, '<p>$1 <a href="#">read more</a><div class="hidden">$2</div></p>', $text, -1, $count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if it you dont need to check if it's in a `<p>` tag you can use something like this:

```
str_replace ( "<!-- pagebreak -->" , '<p>$1 <a href="#">read more</a><div class="hidden">$2</div></p>' , $text, $count );
```

It's a lot lighter to the system.

Comment: I do have to check that, because otherwise I may accidently "hide" the rest of the page. This way I can 'force' the user to use this inside a paragraph only.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you really need to check the needle to be in a paragraph your option is the only one i can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would do the job:

```
$pattern = '#\<p>(.*?)\<!-- pagebreak -->(.*?)\</p>#s';
$text = "<p>some test <!-- pagebreak --> hidden content</p> second test <p>lolo <!-- pagebreak --> more hidden content</p>";

echo preg_replace($pattern, '<p>$1 <a href="#">read more</a><div class="hidden">$2</div></p>', $text, -1, $count);
```

Comment: Yes, but you are assuming here that only one pagebreak exists in one paragraph. My problem is that a user might put two pagebreaks in one paragraph.